# Eclipse: How to set word as auto activation trigger for code completion

Tags: java, eclipse, code-completion

I'd like to have as auto activation trigger for autocompletion in eclipse word "new " (with space included), not only single character. Is this possible?

Thanks

**Note:** This can be found under Window - Preferences - Editor - Content Assist
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, doesn't look like it.  And as I'm sure you already know, just a space triggers on far too many contexts.

Comment: They do, it's nearly unusable to use pure space trigger